# "ImportError: No module named requests;" works in terminal, not in VisualStudio

Tags: python, visual-studio, request, pip

On Ubuntu using VisualStudio. When I run my program, it would output "ImportError: No module named requests".

I found multiple threads on this topic, but the solutions for all of them were that requests might've been installed in a different python version/directory. I believe this isn't the case for me because running "import requests" in terminal doesn't raise an error.

Any thoughts?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random
import webbrowser

def URLgen(model,size):
    base_size = 640
    shoe_size = size - 9.5
    raw_size = int((shoe_size * 20) + base_size)
    url = "http://www.adidas.com/us/" + str(model) + ".html?forceSelSize=" + str(model) + "_" + str(raw_size)
    return url

def check_stock(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    raw_html = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(raw_html.text,"lxml")

    #SelectorGadget to pull CSS code.
    list_raw_sizes = page.select(".size-dropdown-block")

    #Organizing the pulled text.
    sizes = str(list_raw_sizes[0].getText()).replace("\t","")
    sizes = sizes.replace("\n\n"," ")
    sizes.split() #Splits text by default parameter (space).
    sizes.remove("Select")
    sizes.remove("size")
    for size in sizes:
        print(str(model) + "Size:" + str(size) + "Available")

def main(model,size):
    url = URLgen(model,size)
    check_stock(url)
```

EDIT: For context, I'm just messing around with bs4 to write a sneaker bot, but this is very early on in the process.

Comment: How you are running your script in visual studio code?

Comment: @AbdulRehman Just added the code to original post.

Comment: I mean how you are executing this script from visual studio code?

Comment: Using an extension called Code Runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the reference to the `pip` which is going to somewhere else instead of `usr/bin/python`.

So, try to run it from the terminal within the visual studio code **Code > terminal > New Terminal** as `python3 script.py`

You can also take a look at:

When working with Python in VS Code, you select from available environments using the **Python: Select Interpreter** command. The Python extension then uses that selected environment for IntelliSense, auto-completions, linting, formatting, and any other language-related features. (The environment is not, however, used for debugging; see Choose a debugging environment.)

The extension automatically activates the selected environment when you use the **Python: Run Python File in Terminal** and **Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal commands** (as well as **Python: Create Terminal**). To prevent automatic activation, add `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": "false"` to your `settings.json` file.

Installing (or uninstalling) a package in the Terminal with a command like `pip install matplotlib` installs (or uninstalls) the package in whatever environment is active in that Terminal.

Comment: I followed your suggestion regarding running it in a new terminal. The line immediately following "python3 script.py" would've normally returned a value, instead it remains blank and nothing is returned. Is it safe to assume that the request isn't going through, in which case should I be raising an exception?

Comment: Because you haven’t returned anything from main.